# Methods Java Arguments

Tags: java, methods, arguments, switch-statement

To be honest, this is one of the first programs I'm making with a method and I'd like some help on doing the B modification parts. I don't understand what syntax I should use for the arguments in the method, or why I should use that. The method showAll() I've already made and this is the syntax for it, but haven't gotten too far on, any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
private static void showAll(String[] s, int i) { //there is an error with this
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ShowAll");
  System.out.println("Begin");
  System.out.println("End");
}
```

What I need for the showAll():

```
/** create a method named showAll() that:
*   - returns no value
*   - accepts 2 arguments **** (B modification)
*       - an array of type String as an argument
*       - a variable of type int to accept the iMax variable as an argument
*   - contains 
*       - a MessageDialog that displays the message, "ShowAll"
*         **** (B modification) comment out or delete
*       more (B modification)
*       - a loop that outputs all records from 0 to the max i populated
*       - output statements before and after the loop designating begin and end of All
*/
```

Other relevant syntax:
Case Statement

```
switch(strArg) {
      case "A":      
      strArg.equals("A");
      addRec(strRecords, iMax);
      loopQuery();
      break;

      case "F": 
      strArg.equals("F");
      findRec(strRecords, iMax);
      loopQuery();
      break;

      case "S":
      strArg.equals("S");
      showAll(strRecords, iMax);
      loopQuery();
      break;

      default:
      errMessage();
}
```

I really just need to make the method akin to the directions, if anyone could steer me in the path that'd be appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

try using a for loop

```
private static void showAll(String[] s, int i) { //there is an error with this
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ShowAll");
  System.out.println("Begin");

  for (int x = 0; x < s.length && x < i; x++) {
     System.out.println (s[x]);
  }

  System.out.println("End");
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the right `for` loop.  The instructions seem to say to print values from index 0 to the `iMax` (which is the parameter `i`), but that isn't what your code does.

Comment: @ajb - eeek more coffee needed. Fixed I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have a recomendation

it isn't necessary

```
   strArg.equals("A");
```

Because the switch do it

PD: Excuse me, but i am trying to learn English

Comment: doesn't do anything anyway